# unable to edit in Material table when used dropdown

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, edit, reload, material-table

I have used material table to store the data,it contain dropdown iam able to add in the table but when iam trying to edit the table and when onChnage event triggers on Dropdown. page reloads and iam unable to edit the data

Comment: Could you post bit more details like what are you tried , may be a code snipped could explains a lot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.